# How to rearrange list in python

Tags: python, pycharm

I want to rearrange my list in python but there are some rules about it. These next few pictures describe how beavers jump into a hole, while others go accross and the ones in the hole go out.

[Original array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuJzj.png)

[Beavers fill in the hole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvSG9.png)

[Others go accross](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9BhR.png)

[Everyone else come out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRYRt.png)

Now there's where it gets complicated. What if i have [more than 1 hole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27TLQ.png). I've managed to figure out everything myself up to this point. Now all i'm asking is how would any of you approach this and if there's any tricks i could use for sorting the list. This is my code so far:

```
bobri = "54321"
luknje = [4, 2, 4]
bobri_original = bobri
bobri_original_list = list(bobri_original)

bobri_list = list(bobri)

i = 1
gli = 0
for st in range(len(luknje)):
    i = 1
    globina = luknje[st]
    # Prvega zapisem in zbrisem iz glavnega seznama
    last_bober = bobri_list[-1]
    bobri_list.remove(str(last_bober))
    bobri_luknja = [last_bober]

    if globina == 1:
        for n in range(len(bobri_list)):
            bobri_luknja.append(bobri_list[n])
        bobri_list = bobri_luknja
    else:
        while i <= globina - 1:
            last_bober = bobri_list[-1]
            bobri_list.remove(str(last_bober))
            bobri_luknja.append(last_bober)

            if i == globina - 1:
                for n in range(len(bobri_list)):
                    bobri_luknja.append(bobri_list[n])
                bobri_list = bobri_luknja
            i += 1
            gli += 1
```

Comment: Please, post your code as is, not as images.

Comment: those are actual images, not codes

Comment: Yes i actually don't need help with the code, more with solving the problem.

Comment: you should show what coding have you done and I suggest looking at docs first

Comment: You do understand, that for people to help you, they will have to have 4 open tabs with images and 1 tab with your question? If you want to get help, at least don't make it harder for community to give it to you.

Comment: I have added my part

Comment: Please take a moment to improve your questions. Remove any links to pictures or code and replace them with actual picture and code.

Comment: Is the question not understandable?

Comment: what would the sorted answer be for the image with more than 1 hole?

Comment: What is your question here?

Answer (score 2):

Zdravo (:

```
def cross_all_holes(initial_list, hole_depths=[]):
    # Crossing single hole function.
    def cross_the_hole(current_list, hole_depth):
        hole_is_filled = False
        list_len = len(current_list)
        result_list = []
        hole = []
        # While not result list contain all the items
        while len(result_list) < list_len:
            # Filling the hole
            if not hole_is_filled:
                element = current_list.pop()
                hole.append(element)
                # Checking if it's filled
                hole_is_filled = len(hole) == hole_depth
            else:
                # Crossing the filled hole
                if len(current_list):
                    element = current_list.pop()
                # Emptying hole
                elif len(hole):
                    element = hole.pop()
                result_list = [element] + result_list
        return result_list

    # Repeat as much as needed.
    current_list = initial_list
    for hole_depth in hole_depths:
        current_list = cross_the_hole(current_list, hole_depth)
    return current_list
```

Thanks for the task, it was funny (:

```
In [20]: cross_all_holes([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], [1,3])
Out[20]: [9, 8, 7, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's not what i meant. I commented on jlb_gouveia's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Never thought I would write a function with inputs as 'beavers' and 'holes', but thanks for this moment. The beavers is simply the list of the number of each beaver, and holes is the list with each hole, and the amount of beavers getting into each:

```
def rearrange(beavers, holes):
    l = len(beavers)
    for n in range(len(holes)):
        back = beavers[-holes[n]:][::-1]
        front = beavers[:l - holes[n]]
        beavers = back + front
    return(beavers)

rearrange([7,6,5,4,3,2,1], [3])
Out: [1, 2, 3, 7, 6, 5, 4]

rearrange([7,6,5,4,3,2,1], [3,4])
Out: [4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I see what you were trying to do here, you were trying to rearrange them after they come out of the hole. This program has one problem on line 4 it's supposed to be: "back = beavers[:-holes[n]-1:1]".
But that i have already completed and now i tidied the code up a bit.
I wanna know how many holes they have to go through to be the same as they were at the very start, but we have to consider that they come out of the hole in the reverse order they get in.

Comment: Hi @timensmajilovic, fixed it